# Query items that don't have a related record in link table but return results with Id from link table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an Item table:

```
Id | Title  | Active
====================
 1 | Item 1 | 1
 2 | Item 2 | 1
```

A Location table:

```
Id | Name
=========
 1 | A1
 2 | B1
```

and a link table, where EventId specifies a cycle count event:

```
Id | EventId | ItemId | LocationId
=============|====================
1  | 1       | 1      | 2
2  | 1       | 2      | 1
3  | 2       | 1      | 1
4  | 2       | 2      | 2
5  | 3       | 1      | 1
```

I need to determine what items haven't been cycle-counted for a specified EventId (which in this example would be ItemId 2 for EventId 3). We're using a code generation tool that only supports tables and views with a simple filter, so I can't use a sproc or table-valued function. Ideally we'd like to be to do this:

```
SELECT [EventId], [ItemId] FROM [SomeView] WHERE [EventId] = 3
```

and get a result like

```
EventId | ItemId
================
3       | 2
```

I've tried to wrap my head around this -- unsuccessfully -- because I know it's difficult to query a negative. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Is something like the following what you're after?

```
select l.eventId, x.Id ItemId
from Link l
cross apply (
    select *
    from Items i
    where i.Id != l.ItemId
)x
where l.EventId = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--data to work with
DECLARE @items TABLE (ID int, Title nvarchar(100), Active int)
INSERT INTO @items VALUES (1, 'Item 1', 1) 
INSERT INTO @items VALUES (2, 'Item 2', 1)  

DECLARE @location TABLE (ID int, Name nvarchar(100))
INSERT INTO @location VALUES (1, 'A1') 
INSERT INTO @location VALUES (2, 'B1') 

DECLARE @linkTable TABLE (ID int, EventId int, ItemId int, LocationId int)
INSERT INTO @linkTable VALUES (1, 1, 1, 2) 
INSERT INTO @linkTable VALUES (2, 1, 2, 1) 
INSERT INTO @linkTable VALUES (3, 2, 1, 1) 
INSERT INTO @linkTable VALUES (4, 2, 2, 2) 
INSERT INTO @linkTable VALUES (5, 3, 1, 1) 
INSERT INTO @linkTable VALUES (6, 4, 2, 1) 

--query you want
SELECT 3 as EventID, ID as ItemID
FROM @items i
WHERE ID not in (SELECT ItemId 
                 FROM @linkTable 
                 WHERE EventId = 3)
```

Get all the ItemIDs from the LinkTable and then get all the items from the Items table that dont have the sync event. You can replace the 3 in `WHERE` and `SELECT` clauses with whatever event you are looking for. And if you want all such pairs of event + item then this should do it:

```
SELECT subData.EventId, subData.ItemID
FROM (SELECT i.ID as ItemID, cj.EventId
      FROM @items i CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT EventId 
                                FROM @linkTable) cj) subData 
left join  @linkTable lt ON lt.EventId = subData.EventId and lt.ItemId = subData.ItemID
WHERE lt.ID is null
```

This could be heavy on performance because `CROSS JOIN` and `DISTINCT` and subjoins but it gets the job done. At 1st you create a data of all possible items and events pairs, then left join linked table to it and if the linked table's ID is null that means that there is no event + item pair which means that the item is not synced for that event.